# jQuery Virtual Keyboard plugin inserts the same character twice on Windows 8 touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, virtual-keyboard

I'm using a virtual keyboard for jQuery that I got from here (https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/), everything works fine except that on touch screen tablet running Firefox + Windows 8 when I tap on a key it inputs the character twice, this was already reported on the github project page under issues but the developer not responded yet and I'm not able to find the root of this evil, any kind of help is much appreciated!
Thanks

- Project Page: http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/
- GitHub: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/
- Reported Issue: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/184/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem but in qt5.
The double input may be due to the system 
synthesizing an extra mouse event from the primary touch point, resulting
in 2 mouse events instead of one.
One solution would be to replace 'mousedown' keyBinding to just touchstart as follows

```
$(input).keyboard({
 keyBinding   : 'touchstart',
```

Alternatively write a system hook  to filter out MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH events.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer this, the developer was able to sort it out using a delay timer, here's the fix: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/commit/758f7b3a9e5ccc05ae48301f799e643d5b440eb5.